# Order of Fragment and Query in URI

Tags: uri, anchor

According to Wikipedia and to my understanding,
A query like

```
http://www.domain.com/path/?query=value#!/q/testtest
```

is *more correct* than

```
http://www.domain.com/path/#!/q/testtest?query=value
```

Might I encounter any problems if using the second style in HTML links?

Answer (score 1):

Your second URI doesn’t contain a query component.

`http://www.example.com/path/?query=value#!/q/testtest`

- [Path](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.3): `/path/`
- [Query](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.4): `?query=value`
- [Fragment](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.5): `#!/q/testtest`

`http://www.example.com/path/#!/q/testtest?query=value`

- [Path](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.3): `/path/`
- [Query](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.4): *none/empty*
- [Fragment](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.5): `#!/q/testtest?query=value`

> Might I encounter any problems if using the second style in HTML links?

It’s a valid URI.

Comment: The browser uses the query in the second URI the same way. I think the question mark needs to be url encoded for it not to be a query. But maybe the whole question is not really a good one.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: What do you mean by "browser uses"? Your implementation (e.g. JavaScript) might do whatever it wants to do with it, but from the URI standard perspective, the 2nd URI has no query component. Your JS implementation can read/use the content of the fragment component in any way you like.